# Execution of both branches of the IF statement

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

While trying to create a customized DataSource for the SmartGWT's TreeGrid, I found myself in a very peculiar situation. While retrieving the EndRow property of the request, I found that, if it does not exist, the getEndRow function will not return null (or a predefined default value, -1 would have been good enough) but it throws an exception because it tries to convert to int the value of the property (javascript: *undefined*.java_lang_Integer_value). The best thing I could cook up was to put everything in a try catch and have the finally block set a default value.

```java
int end = 0;
try{
    end = request.getEndRow();
}    
catch(Exception ex) {
    // DO NOTHING or something useless
    end = 0;
}
finally{
    if (end == 0 || end > total) {
       end = total;
    }           
}
```

The outputted javascript code looks like this:

```js
try {
    end = com_smartgwt_client_util_JSOHelper_getAttributeAsInt__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_JavaScriptObject_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Integer_2(request.com_smartgwt_client_core_JsObject_jsObj, 'endRow').java_lang_Integer_value;
}
catch ($e0) {
    $e0 = com_google_gwt_lang_Exceptions_caught__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2($e0);
    if (com_google_gwt_lang_Cast_instanceOf__Ljava_lang_Object_2IZ($e0, Q$java_lang_Exception)) {
        end = 0;
    }
    else
        throw $e0;
}
finally {
    (end == 0 || end > this$static.PCSTC_client_NTDataSource_total) && (end = this$static.com_PCSTC_client_NTDataSource_total);
}
```

This is all very well: *getAttributeAsInt* returns undefined, so the **java_lang_Integer_value** does not exist. This causes an exception, which is caught. $e0 exception object is constructed (stacktrace and everything), the check against java_lang_Exception returns *true*, so the *end* variable is set to 0. **The problem is that the next line that will be executed is throw $e0;** 
Not only that this makes no sens, but after the execution of the try/catch/finally blocks I have an uncaught exception: the exception I just handled! **False**: see **Update3**
The question is: what causes the execution of both branches of the if statement and how can I avoid it?

System details: FF 20.0 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 with GWT SDK 2.5.1 and SmartGWT 3.1p

Thanks,
Flo.

**UPDATE**

The stacktrace:

```
"com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) 
 fileName: http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html
 lineNumber: 335
 stack: PCSTC_client_NTDataSource_$executeFetch__LPCSTC_client_NTDataSource_2Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_smartgwt_client_data_DSRequest_2Lcom_smartgwt_client_data_DSResponse_2V@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:335
PCSTC_client_GwtRpcDataSource_transformRequest__Lcom_smartgwt_client_data_DSRequest_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:326
com_smartgwt_client_data_DataSource_onInit__V/self.transformRequest<@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:268
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:571
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:609
@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:594
isc_DataSource_getServiceInputs@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:463
isc_DataSource_sendDSRequest@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:665
isc_DataSource_performDSOperation@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:647
isc_DataSource_fetchData@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:621
isc_ResultTree_loadChildren@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:1366
isc.A.changeDataVisibility@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:90
isc_Tree_openFolder@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:90
isc_Tree_setRoot@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:46
isc_Tree_init@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:25
isc_c_Class_invokeSuper@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:225
isc_ResultTree_init@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:1357
isc_Class_completeCreation@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:263
isc_c_Class_create@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:169
isc_Canvas_createResultTree@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:1415
isc_TreeGrid_createDataModel@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js:1479
isc_Canvas_filterWithCriteria@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2400
isc_Canvas__filter@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2399
isc_c_Class_invokeSuper@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:225
isc_c_Class_Super@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:218
isc_ListGrid__filter@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js:1589
isc_Canvas_fetchData@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/sc/modules/ISC_Core.js:2381
PCSTC_client_SGWT_updateTreeGrid__LPCSTC_client_SPCManager_2V@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:459
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:571
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:609
@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:594
@http://127.0.0.1:8888/SGWT.html:46
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
jQuery.event.trigger@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:2986
.trigger/<@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:3677
.each@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:648
jQuery.prototype.each@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:270
.trigger@http://127.0.0.1:8888/js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.js:3676
com_google_gwt_lang_EntryMethodHolder_init__V@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:983
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:571
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:621
@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:594
gwtOnLoad@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:10220
maybeStartModule@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/PCSTC.SGWT.nocache.js:40
PCSTC_SGWT.onScriptLoad@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/PCSTC.SGWT.nocache.js:278
@http://127.0.0.1:8888/PCSTC.SGWT/95B8D29626B94496F815FE8CECC681AC.cache.html:10228
```

**Update 2**
I should have mentioned that this code runs in production mode, not in development mode, therefore this is the behavior of the javascript code (debugged with FB) not the java code in the browser's VM.

**Update 3**
The boring part: the next line after this unintended try/catch/finally statement generates exactly the same exception. I was just to quick to judge: I presumed it was the exception that I just handled. It is not the case. Therefore, the statement that *after the execution of the try/catch/finally blocks I have an uncaught exception: the exception I just handled* is false. 
The interesting part: I placed some alerts inside the if statement and immediately after the finally statement, like this:

```
1 end = 0;
2 try {
3   end = com_smartgwt_client_util_JSOHelper_getAttributeAsInt__Lcom_google_gwt_core_client_JavaScriptObject_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_Integer_2(request.com_smartgwt_client_core_JsObject_jsObj, 'endRow').java_lang_Integer_value;
4 }
5 catch ($e0) {
6   $e0 = com_google_gwt_lang_Exceptions_caught__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2($e0);
7   if (com_google_gwt_lang_Cast_instanceOf__Ljava_lang_Object_2IZ($e0, Q$java_lang_Exception)) {
8       alert("then");
9       end = 0;
10  }
11  else {
12      alert("else");
13      throw $e0;
14  }
15 }
16 finally {
17     (end == 0 || end > this$static.PCSTC_client_NTDataSource_total) && (end = this$static.PCSTC_client_NTDataSource_total);
18 }
19 alert("outside");
```

The order of highlighting (and execution, I suppose) is the following: 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,**13**,17,**13**,19. The thing that I do not understand is what happens at this line: *throw $e0;*. First of all I did not expect that this line will ever be executed. But it is, so I expect the $e0 to be thrown, but evidently it is not. Another 'quirk' is the fact that line 12 *alert("else");* is never executed.

All in all, if I were not to debug this part of the script, I would have thought that everything is ok, actually the result is the expected one: execute the finally part in case of an exception occurs or not. Combined with the gross oversight from my side, I think I will actually close this thread.

I would greatly appreciate your comments on the execution of the throw statement.

Thanks,
Flo.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `else` before `throw $e0`. I do not believe the code goes into the if-then-block, but goes to the else-block.

```
if (com_google_gwt_lang_Cast_instanceOf__Ljava_lang_Object_2IZ($e0, Q$java_lang_Exception)) {
    alert("reachable?"); // put this line and run your app again.
    end = 0;
}
else
    throw $e0;
```

Remember that SmartGWT/GWT emulates only a subset of Java runtime library. 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation

In your case, `DSResponse.getEndRow()` tries to return an Integer, which is converted from a long (constant `DSRequest.ENDROW_UNSET`). According to your stack trace, GWT throws a JavaScriptException.

The JavaScriptException is not a type of java.lang package, which is perhaps not in the GWT support table. The if-condition is not true, the else-block is triggered.

Comment: I don't know much about SmartGWT/GWT but your answer makes more sense than the execution hitting both the "if" and the "else" branches.

Comment: I'll put tomorrow morning an alert in there, just to be 100% sure that the 'then' branch gets executed. But what I can say for sure is that Firebug shows the execution of the _end = 0_ line and the next line highlighted by FB (and executed) is the throw _$e0_. I checked the if statement in the console and it is interpreted as _true_ (as it ought to be. All exceptions derive from java.lang.exception so I expect that the mapped javascript exceptions respect this hierarchy)

Comment: @Flo, you'd better try chrome and msie as well. They both have great debugging tools. I am afraid FB did not interpret JS code correctly.